# how to update data when i change the value in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, laravel

I want to update data after it change. for example the data is 5 and after i change it to 3 and send it by click the button it stock will be 2 in database. how can i do that in there?

updated the html that might error when add the value

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML++;
    check();
  });

  document.getElementById('less').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML--;
    check();
  });

  function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('val').innerHTML == 1) {
      document.getElementById('less').disabled = true;
    }else if (document.getElementById('val').innerHTML == 5) {
      document.getElementById('add').disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('less').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('add').disabled = false;
    }
    document.getElementById('main_value').value = document.getElementById('val').innerHTML;
  }

  check();

});
```

```html
<form action='/details'>
<div class="content">
<div class="card">
  <img src={{$data->gambar}} alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>{{$data->judul}}</b></h4>
    <p>{{$data->artis}}</p>
    <p>Stock = {{$data->stok}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="pencetan">
<ul>
<li><button id="less">-</button></li>
<li><div id="val">1</div></li>
<input type="hidden" name="val" id="main_value" />
<li><button id="add">+</button></li>
</ul>
<a class="button">Rental</a>
</div>
</form>
```

the Controller

```
     public function details(Request $request, $id){
    $data=Dvd::find($id);
     return view('details', ['data' => $data]);
  }
```

Comment: You should send an ajax request to your controller action, or use a form.

Comment: how to use a form?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms

Comment: but if i use from is it send it the value? like if i change it to 3 and it will send it 3

Comment: Create hidden field and update if when you update the div value, then when you'll submit the updated value will be sent.

Comment: could you give me some example?

Comment: Check the posted example...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a form with hidden input to send the value to your `something` link. then in your controller add another action `something` :

```
public function something(Request $request){
    //Here you get your value
    $new_stock = $request->get('main_value');

    //Here we get the id of specific Dvd
    $stock_id = $request->get('object_id');

    //Here we update the DB
    Dvd::find($stock_id)->update(['stock' => $new_stock]);
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML++;
    check();
  });

  document.getElementById('less').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('val').innerHTML--;
    check();
  });

  function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('val').innerHTML == 1) {
      document.getElementById('less').disabled = true;
    } else if (document.getElementById('val').innerHTML == 5) {
      document.getElementById('add').disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('less').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('add').disabled = false;
    }

    document.getElementById('main_value').value = document.getElementById('val').innerHTML;

    console.log("The value that will be submited is " + document.getElementById('main_value').value);
  }

  check();

});
```

```html
<form action='/something'>
  <p>Stock = 5</p>
  <ul>
    <li><button id="less" type="button">-</button></li>
    <li>
      <div id="val">1</div>
      <input type="hidden" name="val" id="main_value" />
      <input type="hidden" name="object_id" value="{{$data->id}}" />
    </li>
    <li><button id="add" type="button">+</button></li>
  </ul>
  <button class="button">Rental</button>
</form>
```

Comment: how do i post the `main_value` to database?

Comment: Are you sure you're using laravel? If yes then your route `/something` should be related to an action in some controller. isn't it ?

Comment: yes sure. i updated my question and add the code you give before but when i add the value it suddenly direct to something else

Comment: the stock is actually comes from database and i want only stock can updated in database

Comment: Add please to question the content of your controller too

Comment: You should link the action with your route in route file, check the action added to my post.

Comment: `$details = Dvd::create([
      'stok' => $request->input('stok')
    ]);` is like this the code should i write to update db?

Comment: You want to update the stock of specific Dvd?!! then you should know the `id` of this object, so we'll have to add another input hidden to send the `id` too, I will update.

Comment: yes right. the id also in db. thats why in my controller i'm find($id)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176585/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-mo-ne).